# What files set the default PATH

Tags: debian, environment-variables, login, startup

I'm puzzled as to what files set *the default* `PATH` on Linux (specifically, Debian). (I'm not interested in the user-specific ones in `~` (`.profile`, `xsessionrc`, maybe others) here.)

So far I've ruled out the (not-so-)usual suspects `/etc/{environment,bash.bashrc,login.defs,profile,crontab,security/pam_env.conf,default/locale,default/cron,pam.d/sshd,pam.d/cron}` and `/usr/sbin/sshd` but still my default `PATH` is set to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` every time I log in. Grepping for "/local/games" in `/etc` turns up nothing. I suspect it's hard coded in a binary somewhere. I'm using `bash`

Comment: @waltinator There's nothing beyond `/etc/profile` [there](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/login.defs` file?

Comment: @StephenKitt I do, but the paths are `ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
                          ENV_PATH PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` there

Comment: Is this logging in at a console (VT), an X11 session with desktop environment, or over SSH?

Comment: @bk2204 X11 session w/ Xfce

Answer (score 3):

##### In a nutshell, an empirical rule for a *standard* user, on Debian 11

1. `/etc/profile`, sets the authoritative PATH;
2. `/etc/environment` or `/etc/default/locale`;
3. `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games` (if GDM,XDM... or OpenSSH);
4. `/etc/login.defs`' `ENV_PATH` option (if console);
5. fallback on `getconf PATH` -- or C equivalent (if console).

*if GDM,XDM... or OpenSSH* means: if your session is a graphical desktop or SSH.

*if console* means : if your session is a console, ie not in a graphical desktop or SSH (see below).

This should not fit on `su` nor `sudo` environments.

Below, we assume the user logs out/in between each test.

---

##### A test setup

- `VERSION="11 (bullseye)"`
- Display Manager: GDM3
- Desktop: **Gnome**, terminal: **gnome-terminal**, shell: **bash**

Afer removing user's `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile`, the command `printenv PATH` returns : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`.  A search on this string in `/etc` pops up the `/etc/profile` file.

###### First step: change `/etc/profile` and see how it goes

After commenting out `/etc/profile` lines 4-9 (PATH manipulation section),
`printenv PATH` then says: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games`.  The lack of `/usr/local/games` in the PATH shows the action had an effect on the system,  sweet!

###### Next step: look for `/usr/games` string wherever we can

Things become a bit more tricky, you'd need to install source packages `xdm`, `gdm3`, `lightdm`, `openssh`.  Then looking for `/usr/games` shows that three of them (`xdm`, `gdm3`, `openssh`) set some kind of `default_path` in `debian/rules` file.

Gdm3's code states that this value is used if [pam_getenv(3)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pam_getenv.3) doesn't return a PATH value.

*The lightdm case:*

This one is slightly different, there is a `debian/patches/01_set-default-path.patch` file that hard-codes the path in the source code (instead of a compilation parameter).

*Warning*: the Debian maintainer used *the very same PATH sequence* than `/etc/profile` (`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`).  Harder to notice a change by commenting code in this case.

###### Next step: look at `/etc/pam.d` policies

The file `/etc/pam.d/gdm-launch-environment` seems to be a good candidate.  It sources two files:

- `/etc/environment`;
- `/etc/default/locale` (you shouldn't put PATH declaration here ^^).

Long story short, we did not check all possible behaviors, but GDM and OpenSSH behaved the same, so you can bet this is the Debian way :

- **if** `/etc/profile` does not set PATH

  - **if** you set a `PATH=/somepath` entry in `/etc/environment`

    - this entry is applied,
  - **else**

    - compiled fallback is used (`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games`)

###### Strip down a bit more

So, OpenSSH and DMs override empty `PATH` variable, but the console does not use them.  It turns out that when `/etc/profile`'s PATH section is commented and the `/etc/environment` file is empty (default state), then a third PATH value is used: the `/etc/login.defs` ENV_PATH option.

You may comment `/etc/login.defs` line 103 to get something like :

```
$ grep -nE '^#?ENV_(SU)?PATH' /etc/login.defs 
102:ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
103:#ENV_PATH   PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Then you can log in a console (serial and TTY *should* behave the same) and play `printenv PATH` again. This time it should display: `/bin:/usr/bin`.  This is equal to `getconf PATH` on my system, so I think we've reach the bottom there.

###### Other (maybe) intersting points

Note that OpenSSH and Graphical Display sessions *break* environment variables inheritance (cf [environ(7)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/environ.7)).

Answer (score 1):

There are many places in a Linux system where the `PATH` variable may be set or updated.  This depends on the mode of accessing the system and the software involved (the SSH daemon, `sshd`, for example, contains a hard-coded value for `PATH`).  I don't know where the value you see on your system is set. So in this answer, I'm instead addressing the suspicion you mention at the end of the question.

The `bash` executable contains a default value for the `PATH` variable.

When compiling the `bash` shell from the source code, one can modify the file [`config-top.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/config-top.h).  This file contains various compile-time settings that would typically be changed by a system distributor (package maintainer) to conform to the flavour of their operating system distribution.

One of the things that this file sets is the `DEFAULT_PATH_VALUE` macro's value.  The value that is set in the shell's distributed sources is the string

```c
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:.
```

This will be what is outputted by the command

```bsh
env -i bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'
```

This would output the value of the `PATH` variable from a shell that does not inherit any environment variables from the parent shell, and that does not source any shell initialization files.